# Uninstall Android Studio

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

I'm having a problem while trying to uninstall Android Studio (2020.3.1) in Windows 10.
When I click on "Uninstall" in "Add or remove programs", it says that the file "D:\Android\Android Studio\uninstall.exe" doesn't exist. Indeed, it isn't in that folder, the one where Android Studio is installed.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1669894/file-unistall-exe-missing-in-android-studio-artic-fox-2020-3-1). Please [contact support](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

If the Android Studio installation is missing its uninstall,
just install Android Studio again in order to fix the installation
and then be able to uninstall it correctly.

If you also wish to ensure that there are no left-overs from it,
use an uninstaller such as
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)
to scan for left-overs after the uninstallation is complete.